# How to split char and digit in c

Tags: c, string, split

input(string): E2

output:

The char is E

The num is 2

How can I get that?
Thanks

I use strtol, but it just work for only the first char is num
if my input was 2E, it works, but if it was E2,then fail.

```
int main()
{
    char str[30] = "2E";
    char *ptr;
    long ret;

    ret = strtol(str, &ptr, 10);
    printf("The number(unsigned long integer) is %ld\n", ret);
    printf("String part is %s", ptr);

    return(0);
}
```

What I want is if I input E2, the ret is 2 and the ptr is E

Comment: Please be more specific what input you want to allow: Are you parsing a chessboard position? A hex number? Any cimbination of a single letter and a single decimal digit?

Comment: @MOeh The first char is a single letter and the second is a decimal number.

Comment: If `str` contains `"E2"`, what do you expect to get in `ret`? And you write "then fails". How does it fail ??

Comment: @MichaelWalz The code above is worked. But if my input is E2, then it will get ""The number(unsigned long integer) is 0, "String part is E2."

Comment: @MichaelWalz My exception when I input E2 ,the ret is 2 and the ptr is E

Comment: What is the relevance of *"unsigned long integer"*?

Comment: Are you saying that an input of `"E1234"` and an input of `"2E"` must both isolate one letter and a number?

Comment: @Luke that's not how [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) works. Read the [docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf):

```
char c;
int i;
if (sscanf(input, "%c%d", &c, &i) == 2) /* make sure 2 objects were read */
    printf("The char is %c and the int is %d\n", c, i);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
int main()
{
    char str[30] = "E2";
    char ptr[2];
    long ret;

    ptr[0] = str[0];
    ptr[1] = '\0';
    ret = strtol(str + 1, NULL, 10);

    printf("The number(unsigned long integer) is %ld\n", ret);
    printf("String part is %s", ptr);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: However, stackptr's solution is probably a better choice.